# Search for pattern in web page links and store results to array

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for help storing links to an array if a patten is found. What I have set up so far is a form with a web browser and loaded my page.

I need to search for links which follow the format below and store the word(s) after `page=` into the array. I have trawled the web for answers with no luck

```
/Contacts/Index/Neutral?page=John
/Contacts/Index/Neutral?page=Peter%20Piper
/Contacts/Index/Neutral?page=Mary
```

How would I search for the word after the `=` character in each link and store them in an array?

Comment: Btw, I like this questions much more than your other one. Good job! There's just one thing, you don't actually have a question. "Any help is appreciated" is not a good question, because it's too broad. You even have a question in your title, so you can use that instead. It helps future visitors that perhaps are looking for the same answer as you know that the *actual question* in your post is answered below. This is just my thoughts btw, there's so many people on SO that "asks" "any help..." so perhaps everyone else thinks it's okay. :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) with it's [Query property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx)

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri ("http://www.contoso.com/");
Uri myUri = new Uri (baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");

Console.WriteLine (myUri.Query); //outputs "?date=today"
```

Comment: Just had a quick read up on it and it is close to what I need. I'm trying to do this on the fly from the web page that is loaded in the web browser and just take the word after = Is this capable of that?

Comment: @DesHutch: Use `Substring` and `LastIndexOf` on the string, similar to what you did in your other question. `string name = myUri.Substring(myUri.LastIndexOf('='));`